# What does ...지군 하다 mean? When is it used?

Tags: verb, north-korean, conjugation

What is ...지군 하다 ending used for?
For example, 이어지군 하는데 or 하였다.

자기 일터에 대한 많고많은 자랑을 하나둘 꼽아갈 때마다 종업원들의 이야기는 저도모르게 직장장에 대한 이야기로 이어지군 하였다.

Comment: I have added the "north-korean" tag. According to [this page](http://www.tufs.ac.jp/ts/personal/choes/korean/nanboku/Snanboku.html#2.6), "-군 하다" is North Korean for the South Korean "-곤 하다." 직장장 is a North Korean word.

Answer (score 1):

I felt the entire sentence felt awkward though I get the meaning, and I figrued out why with Klmo's clarification in the comment. So, it's NK dialect?

I think it should mean ~지곤 하다 in SK language.
Its basic form is from ~하고는 하다= ~하곤 하다.
It's a matter of verb endings.

It means "used to do~~" or "used to be ~~"

Answer (score 1):

It should be "~하곤 하다", NOT "~하군 하다".

> 자기 일터에 대한 많고많은 자랑을 하나둘 꼽아갈 때마다 종업원들의 이야기는 저도모르게 직장장에 대한 이야기로 이어지군 하였다.

Above sentence could be translated as follows:

> As keep mentioning about proud things of their workplace, workers used to begin to talk about their workplace.